# Extracting rows from file to file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a txt file containing many rows.

###### id.txt

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

I have a second larger txt file (2-6 GB) that contains many rows including the rows of the first file.

###### reference.txt

```
@xxxx zzz yyyy
1235804864
@abce zzz yyyy
1354867435
@xxxx zzz yyyy
3541687281
```

I want to extract from the second file, the lines that contain that 'xxxx' and the line after.

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
while read p; do grep -A1 "$p" reference.txt > output.txt; done<id.txt
```

Comment: please update the question to explain what *`doesn't seem to work'* means ... error message? no output? wrong output? something else?  and if the answer is 'wrong output' then also update the question with the 'wrong output'

Comment: will the `id.txt` file contain duplicates as you've shown (eg, `xxxx` listed 4 times)? if `id.txt` may contain duplicates ... please confirm that you want to generate 'duplicate' sets of output ... or do you want to generate a unique set of outputs?

Comment: could a search string (eg, `xxxx`) occur on consecutive lines (eg, `xxxx` \n `xxxx` `123456`)?  if the answer is 'yes', please update the question with an example input and the expected output

Comment: `grep -Ff id.txt -A1 reference.txt >output.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to use `>>` (append) instead of `>`
This code should work:

```
while read -r p; do grep -A 1 -F "$p" "reference.txt" >> output.txt ; done < "id.txt"
```

Comment: alternatively, move the redirection outside the loop